# Javascript Promise resolving in catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, es6-promise

I have a function sendMail that returns a promise.

```
module.exports = function sendMail(mailData) {

const smtpConfig = {
 service: 'gmail',
 auth: {
   user: MAIL_USER,
   pass: MAIL_PASS
 }
};

const trans = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
 trans.sendMail(mailData, (err, result) => {
   if (err) {
     console.log('error', err)
     reject(err);
   }
   else {
     console.log('no error', result)
     resolve(result);
   }
  });
 });
}
```

The promise resolves and the logged output from this is:

```
no error { accepted: [ 'test@test.com' ],
rejected: [],
response: '250 2.0.0 OK 1488900621 j79sm6419250itb.0 - gsmtp',
envelope: { from: '', to: [ 'test@test.com' ] },
messageId: '<511ca80b-0bec-2d06-8f52-81194bcbf26b@My-MacBook-Pro.local>' }
```

And the email is sent.
However calling the function from another module, the result gets passed to the .catch block as an error.

```
 module.exports = User = {

 sendMail(mailData)
   .then((result) => {
     console.log('here', result)
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.log('error', err)
   });

}
```

Produces the identical output but as an error in the catch block:

```
error { accepted: [ 'test@test.com' ],
rejected: [],
response: '250 2.0.0 OK 1488900621 j79sm6419250itb.0 - gsmtp',
envelope: { from: '', to: [ 'test@test.com' ] },
messageId: '<511ca80b-0bec-2d06-8f52-81194bcbf26b@MY-MacBook-Pro.local>' }
```

And the .then block never runs.

Any help as to what I'm missing here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _However calling the function from another module_ - where do you call it when it works OK?

Comment: One issue I see with your code is `return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {` which should be `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`  The resolver combes before the rejector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here:

```
return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
```

you mixed up the order of function parameters. Your function will be passed `resolve` first and `reject` second no matter how you name it, so your `resolve` will act as `reject` and vice versa.

It should be:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

The names of the arguments to the function that you pass to the Promise constructor doesn't matter, but the order matters. So for example you can use this to produce a resolved promise:

```
new Promise((x, y) => x(123));
// same as Promise.resolve(123);
```

or this to produce a rejected promise:

```
new Promise((x, y) => y(123));
// same as Promise.reject(123);
```

but if you switch the `x` and `y` then it will be different - now `x` rejects:

```
new Promise((y, x) => x(123));
// same as Promise.reject(123);
```

and `y` resolves:

```
new Promise((y, x) => y(123));
// same as Promise.resolve(123);
```

See the docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> new Promise( /* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } );
> ```

So the mystery is not why it doesn't work but why it works in some other module. Maybe it does something like:

```
Promise.reject(3).catch(e => e).then(val => console.log('val:', val));
```

but using your function instead of `Promise.reject(3)` and using some other logic instead of `console.log`, of course.

Comment: Wow I figured it was something small but it escaped me. Thanks for taking the time @rsp.

Comment: Just to mention: the order of `catch` and `then` here may affect the callings, so `Promise.reject(3).then(val => console.log('val:', val)).catch(e => e)` will never call _then_ block, it has to be after the _catch_ to get affected